# PyScript Syntax Error when page is loaded on github pages

Tags: pyscript

Below code **works well on local host**.
but when the page is loaded on the github pages(jekyll blog), it doesn't work with error message which is `JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 421, in eval_code CodeRunner( File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 237, in __init__ self.ast = next(self._gen) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 141, in _parse_and_compile_gen mod = compile(source, filename, mode, flags | ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "", line 1 from js import document def main(): content = document.getElementById('test3').children[0]; content.innerHTML = 'output3' main() ^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax )`.

What's happening...T_T

**+Details Added:**

- Below code is written on the markdown file.
- Error occurs when deploy on github pages.
- My operation system is windows 10.

```html
<!-- PyScript -->
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<div id="test3">
  <p style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: orange;">Loading...</p>
</div>

<py-script>
from js import document

def main():
    content = document.getElementById('test3').children[0];
    content.innerHTML = 'output3'

main()
</py-script>
```

Comment: My guess is that you have a file format problem. The browser (PyScript) thinks your Python code is one line. This indicates a line ending problem (\n versus \r\n). Edit your question with more details on the editor you are using and the OS version, browser version, etc.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley.
I found the kramdown processor doesn't break line of <py-script> when parsing .md to .html while deploying.
The problem has been solved by enclosing <py-script> with <pre> tag.
It's just expedient.
I still don't understand kramdown parser works differently in localhosting and deploying github pages.

Comment: FYI: You are using the words **local host** and **localhosting** incorrectly which can cause confusion. The word **localhost** refers to a hostname. All computers with TCP/IP installed have a **localhost** hostname alias. Instead use words like my desktop computer, cloud virtual machine, etc.